# What do 'sigma' and 'pi' in front of ligands in the formula of a coordination compound mean?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds, terminology

The following coordination compound was given in the book Concise Inorganic Chemistry by J.D. Lee (Adapted by Sudarsan Guha) under the topic 'Effective Atomic Number (EAN)':

$\ce{[Ti(\sigma -C5H5)2 (\pi  -C5H5)2]^0}$

What is meant by the quantifiers $\sigma$ and $\pi$ in front of the ligand?  I have not seen this format with other ligands? If this is to signify $\sigma$ and $\pi$ bonds, why is it not used in the formulas of metal carbonyls which have synergic bonds (a combination of both $\sigma$ and $\pi$ bonds)?

In all the 67 occurrences of 'cyclopentadienyl' in the [IUPAC Red Book](https://iupac.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Red_Book_2005.pdf), I was unable to see $\ce{C5H5-}$ having a $\sigma$ or $\pi$ in front of it. Instead I only saw $\eta$ being used in the name. I came to know that it is meant to denote '[hapticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hapticity)'. Is this related to the presence of $\sigma$, $\pi$?

Comment: This question is similar to yours: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66911/%CE%B71-or-sigma-complex-involving-cyclopentadienyl-anion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Concise Inorganic Chemistry<sup>1</sup> has the following to say about this tetra(cyclopentadienyl) titanium complex:

> Tetra(Cyclopentadienyl) compounds such as $\ce{Ti(C5H5)4}$ may be made from $\ce{TiCl4}$ and $\ce{Na(C5H5)}$. The formula may be written as $\ce{[Ti(\eta_5-C5H5)2(\eta_1-C5H5)2]}$ where two cyclopentadienyl rings are attached by 5 C-atoms ($\pi$ - bonded) and two rings are attached by one C-atom ($\sigma$ - bonded).
>
> NMR studies on these tetra(cyclopentadienyl) compounds suggest that in the $\eta_1$ rings the C bonded to Ti continually changes, and the $\eta_1$ and $\eta_5$ rings change their roles.

The first paragraph explains quite well what the author intends by the quantifiers $\sigma$ and $\pi$. Two rings are bonded by $\pi$ donation with a hapticity of 5 and two rings are $\sigma$ bonded with a hapticity of 1. This picture should clear things up

[image: Ti(C5H5)4 structure]

**References**:

1. Lee, J. D. Concise Inorganic Chemistry. 5th ed, *Wiley publishers & Blackwell Science*, *pp. 696*, **1996**